# Does using a photo from Google Photos in a Google Doc cause it to be counted twice against the storage allocation?

Tags: google-photos, image-storage

Photos in Google Photos count against the storage allocation for the account
(though some have a billing waiver in effect, if taken on a Pixel phone).

If such a photo is incorporated into another Google product, such as Google Docs, does each use count anew for storage? How about if sent in an email?

Has anyone done the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, May 8th, 2021, no, but starting on June 1, 2021, yes, as Google Docs will count against Google Accounts storage quota.

NOTES:

- Currently when a image is inserted to a document it creates a copy of the image.
- On Google Documents only tables and charts from Google Sheets have a link to the source (they can be updated by clicking a button)
- As at this time Google Docs doesn't count against the Google Account quota storage there is no way to know if the impact will be doubling the used quota or if will be some sort of storage optimization.

Resources

- [Insert or delete images & videos](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447?hl=en)
- [Upcoming changes to how your Google storage works](https://support.google.com/googleone/answer/9312312?hl=en)

Comment: Looks like we'll have to wait until June to test this out!

Comment: I can't quite tell.  Maybe they grandfathered existing google docs?

Comment: @Bryce According to https://support.google.com/googleone/answer/9312312?hl=en only old docs edited after the specified date will count against the quota, unedited docs will not.